# In EXWM `split-window-right` followed by immediate `windmove-right` swaps order of buffers

Tags: window, window-splitting, exwm

I have a function

```
(defun bad-fn ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (windmove-right)
  )
```

If I go to a frame with just one window visiting EXWM buffer A (and buffer B
is next), and call

- `split-window-right`
- `windmove-right`

Manually with M-x, I have A to the left of B, and B is the selected
window.

If I use the above function, I have B to the left of A, and A is the
selected window.

Changing the above to

```
(defun bad-fn ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
    (sit-for 0.5)
  (windmove-right)
  )
```

fixes things.

Emacs version info: "GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+
Version 3.24.22, cairo version 1.17.3) of 2020-08-28"

As a note, I don't think this happened in Emacs 26.3.

Comment: If I split a window, I'll have (and *expect* to have) the same buffer in each window -- i.e. A and B are the same buffer -- so I'm confused by your question from the outset.  Is your recipe starting from `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Oh, shoot my bad. Edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You may have more control, no timing issues and fewer layers of debugging to do using built-in functions.

My equivalent to your function is something I use every day in EXWM.

```el
(defun gjg/split-window-right ()
  "Split window right, switch to the new window AND switch buffer in that window"
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (other-window 1)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))
```